# Active character and delimited argument

Tags: tex-core

Say I have a macro `\foo` that takes one argument, delimited at start and at end by a `!`. The problem is that I don't know at the time of the call of `\foo` if `!` has been made `\active` by, say, french `babel`.

For now, I use the following approach. It works but I need to maintain two version of the same macros, one dealing with non active `!` and the other with active `!`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
  \catcode`\!=12\relax
  \gdef\foo@nonactive!#1!{Non active: #1.}
  \catcode`\!=\active\relax
  \gdef\foo@active!#1!{Active: #1.}
\endgroup

\def\foo{%
  \ifnum\the\catcode`\!=\active\relax
    \expandafter\foo@active
  \else
    \expandafter\foo@nonactive
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\catcode`\!=12\relax
\foo!bar!
\catcode`\!=\active\relax
\def !{This exclamation mark is active}
\foo!bar!!

\end{document}
```

**Question**

Is this approach robust and is there an other way to do that (with and/or without `eTeX`).

Comment: If this turns out to be a good approach, I can reformulate the question and post the code as an answer.

Comment: I'd avoid an expansion step by saying ``\AtBeginDocument{\ifnum\catcode`\!=\active\let\foo\foo@active\else\let\foo\foo@nonactive\fi}`` as babel activates the characters at begin document.

Comment: @egreg Ok. But I forgot to say that it must be generic.

Comment: @egreg The `\AtBeginDocument` trick must be written after `\usepackage[french]{babel}` if I understand correctly, as `\AtBeginDocument` builds a kind of FIFO stack.

Comment: Yes, of course. One can use `\AfterEndPreamble` of `etoolbox` to ensure that the code is executed after `babel` activations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternative is:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\makeatletter


\def\foo#1{\def\foo@##1#1{[non]active ##1}\foo@}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\catcode`\!=12\relax
\foo!bar!
\catcode`\!=\active\relax
\def !{This exclamation mark is active}
\foo!bar!!

\end{document}
```

---

As noted by egreg in the comments this definition is "fragile", if you try

```
\tableofcontents
\section{ aaa \protect\foo\protect!ddd\protect! bbb }
```

Things die horribly as the inner `\def` inside `\foo` can not happen during  a `\write` (to write the `.toc` file).

If you try

```
\tableofcontents
\section{ aaa \protect\foo!ddd! bbb }
```

Then @egreg pointed out that things would still fail as then `\foo` would not expand, but both `!` *would* expand so would not be available as delimiters. Shorthands can in fact be defined to be self-protecting so in an environment that requires protection they should expand to themselves (like `\noexpand!`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\def\foo#1{\def\foo@##1#1{[non]active ##1}\foo@}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\catcode`\!=12\relax
\foo!bar!
\catcode`\!=\active\relax
\def !{\ifx\protext\relax This exclamation mark is active\else\noexpand!\fi}
\foo!bar!!

\tableofcontents

\section{ aaa \protect\foo!ddd! bbb }

\end{document}
```

Comment: However this is not expandable and with `\protect` in front of it, a following active character would be expanded. :(

Comment: @egreg don't move the goal posts:-) anyway presumably in a setting needing protect the active character would/should be defined to expand to itself so everything will work out OK in the end.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hum interesting since expandability is not a requirement. Could you please add some details regarding egreg's comment and yours. Thanks.

Comment: answer expanded as requested

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok. Thanks. And what do you mean by "would/should be defined to expand to itself so everything will work out OK in the end"?

Comment: I defined ! in the revised example to show that, if `\protect` has a non trivial defintion `!` expands to `\noexpand!` which means (if you look in the .toc file) you see `!` there rather than an inappropriate premature expansion of `!`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general solution (taken from `regexpatch.sty`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_ddef_commands_seq
\tl_new:N \l_ddef_prefix_tl
\tl_new:N \l_ddef_arg_tl
\tl_new:N \l_ddef_replacement_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \delimited #1 \def #2
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_ddef_commands_seq { #2 }
  #1 \tex_def:D #2
 }
\AtBeginDocument{
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_ddef_commands_seq { \ddef_normalize:N #1 }
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ddef_normalize:N #1
 {
   \tl_set:Nf \l_ddef_prefix_tl { \token_get_prefix_spec:N #1 }
   \tl_set_rescan:Nnx \l_ddef_prefix_tl { } \l_ddef_prefix_tl
   \tl_set:Nf \l_ddef_arg_tl { \token_get_arg_spec:N #1 }
   \tl_set_rescan:Nnx \l_ddef_arg_tl { } \l_ddef_arg_tl
   \tl_set:Nf \l_ddef_replacement_tl { \token_get_replacement_spec:N #1 }
   \tl_set_rescan:Nnx \l_ddef_replacement_tl { } \l_ddef_replacement_tl
   \use:x
     {
      \exp_not:V \l_ddef_prefix_tl
      \tex_def:D
      \exp_not:N #1
      \exp_not:V \l_ddef_arg_tl
      { \exp_not:V \l_ddef_replacement_tl }
     }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\delimited\def\foo!#1!{Whatever with #1}

\delimited\long\def\bar+#1+{Another with #1}

\begin{document}

\foo!x!

\number\catcode`!

\bar+y+

\number\catcode`+

\show\bar
\end{document}
```

This will print

> Whatever with x
>   13
>   Another with y
>   12

Basically we remember all commands that are defined with `\delimited\def`; prefixes such as `\long` or `\protected` must go between those two tokens, but using `\protected` can open a can of worms if the command is used in a moving argument. Then at begin document, so after `babel` has possibly activated some characters, the commands are rebuilt under the current category codes.

Notice that also the tokens in the replacement text will possibly change category code, but this shouldn't be a problem.

By loading `regexpatch` the code is simpler:

```
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \g_ddef_commands_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \delimited #1 \def #2
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_ddef_commands_seq { #2 }
  #1 \tex_def:D #2
 }
\AtBeginDocument{
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_ddef_commands_seq { \ddef_normalize:N #1 }
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ddef_normalize:N #1
{
 \xpatch_get_all:N #1
 \xpatch_rebuild:N #1
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

### Note

If we want to be sure that the code is performed after `babel` has activated the characters (but `babel` should be among the package loaded very early) one can say

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
```

and use `\AfterEndPreamble` instead of `\AtBeginDocument`.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. This approach is really interesting but unusable in my case since I need something generic.

Comment: @cjorssen This *is* generic! Please, make an example.

Comment: Really sorry. Maybe wrong vocabulary. I meant I cannot rely on `expl3`. I'm looking for something working out of the box with a pure `TeX`-syntax for `plain`, `latex` or `context` formats. However, I must acknowledge it was not stated in my question.